# Find sum between a date range using values from two columns

Tags: hive

I am looking to find a way to figure how to reach the output in table C using Table A and Table B in Hive.

Thanks
Anil

[Table A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GWm9.png)

[Table B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zkDW.png)

[Table C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjZce.png)

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: It will be helpful instead of sharing images if you post the some table script and required results.... and have you tried anything?

Comment: or at least describe some logic behind those figures in simple words.